# Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView-TokenAutoComplete

Tags: android, tags, keyword, tokenautocomplete

I implemented `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` tags using this example:

https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/

But the problem is how to restrict the user to delete the particular tag when user press android native delete button in the key board, and how to enable `onClick` only on cross symbol.

Comment: Please post the relevant code parts here. And try to make a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (also called SO)! I formatted the function (`onClick`), and tag that you mentioned because they are code. I also changed the casing of the words at the beginning of your sentences. Lastly, I removed the closing that was at the end of your post, as it is distracting in the question. Please post you code with formatting, and point out the  issue you are having more. Hope you get your answer!